# Passing a value back to a module

Tags: node.js, jquery, express

I just started to look at node and I don't understand how I can pass a value back to a module... I've searched and searched but its just not clicking so I thought I'd ask.

My app.js contains:

```
app.get('/test', controller.test);
```

My module.js contains:

```
exports.test = function(req, res){
    console.log("Called test Successfully");
    res.json(200, {message: 'success'});
}
```

My index.jade contains:

```
$('.someID').on('click', function(){
    $.get('/test');
});
```

What I'd like to be able to do is pass something from my index.jade back to the module so I can see it in the console.log.... console.log("Called test Successfully" + somevalue);

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply send some parameters ([as `data`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)) and use the [`request.query` property](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.query):

```
/* Serverside */
exports.test = function(req, res){
    console.log("Called 'test' successfully with", req.query.somevalue);
    res.json(200, {message: 'success'});
};
```

```
/* Clientside */
$('#someID').on('click', function(){
    $.get('/test', {somevalue: "foobar"});
});
```

Comment: Gah, I tried that originally but it didn't work... now it does, I guess I made a mistake before. Thanks so much for the reply :)